# Unable to Install Guard

Tags: 13.10, ruby, gem

I've seen Guard and it's usefulness in web development and would like to install it. Naturally, I expected to be able to use `sudo gem install guard` to do so (yes, it is a Ruby Gem). However the installation errors out. Here is what I'm getting:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing guard:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out my problem. After looking at the error, I realised the problem was that mkmf was not installed. To fix this, I ran the command, `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`. After that, everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Download Guard via Mozilla and then install.
Option 2. Try to update again `sudo apt-get update`          Then `sudo apt-gem-update`       Then try `sudo gem-get install guard` 
( or `sudo gem install guard` )

Comment: Where is the Mozilla download? The second option didn't work.

Comment: I'm glad you. Found your answer! It means 'apt-get install moza-ruby' moza is Mozilla Firefox download